# batch findstr not working with string saved in a variable

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file, findstr

I'm trying to find a string inside a *file.txt* using *findstr* and I have the following issue:

`set "log_file=C:\Tools_Dev\log_file.txt"`
a-`findstr C/:"text to find" %log_file%`

works perfectly, now when I try this:

`set "my_variable=text to find"`
b- `findstr C/:"%my_variable%" %log_file%`

I have no output. Option *a-* returns the line where the string is, but *b-* gives me nothing even when "text to find" is the same in both cases
I'm going mad over this. If someone knows where is my mistake or if there is a workaround, would be my hero.

I don't know if it matters but this is from a batch file and I'm trying to find the mistake running the lines in the command-line. Win10

Comment: Use `/C:` not `C/:`  ... **[`findstr /C:"text or variable to find" %log_file%`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)**

Answer (score 0):

I tried with

```
findstr "%my_variable%" %log_file%
```

and worked!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).